# Python problem to fetch image from html form

Tags: python

Want an image from HTML form to python script how can id do this suggest, views.py is my python script.

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <form action="views.py" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    Image:
    <input type="file" name="image" accept="image/*" id="image" required>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" required>
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Where's your python-code? What have you tried?

Comment: i want this image in python code so that i can process it

Answer (score 0):

You have to upload the file from html and save in a particular folder. Then you can use that image again from views.py.

**yourUploadImage.html** :

```
<html>

<head>
  <title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <form action="views.py" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    Image:
    <input type="file" name="image" accept="image/*" id="image" required>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" required>
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```

**routes.py :**

```
@app.route("/imagesubmit", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def imagesubmit():
    if request.form.get('submit') == 'submit':
        f = request.files['image']
        filename = secure_filename(f.filename)
        f.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename))
        return redirect(url_for('viewimage'))
    return render_template('yourUploadImage.html', form=form )
```

To view :

**routes.py**

```
@app.route("/viewimage", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def viewimage():
    myimage = fnmatch.filter(os.listdir(os.path.join(app.static_folder, "img")))
    return render_template('viewImage.html', item=item, myimage=myimage )
```

**Viewimage.html**

```
{% for photo in myimage %}
    <a target="_blank" href="{{ url_for('static' , filename='img/' + photo) }}"><img src="{{ url_for('static' , filename='img/' + photo) }}" class="img-rounded" alt="Cinque Terre" width="304" height="236" ></a>
{% endfor %}
```

and in config.py:

```
import os
basedir = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
class Config(object):
    UPLOAD_FOLDER = os.getcwd() + '/app/static/img/'
```

You might need to change a bit. But the logic is same. Save the image in a folder and extract from there for view.

Comment: Please check the answer has been updated as per your query.

Comment: basically i want to store image in any variable and then want to process that image

Comment: ohhh... no you cant store the image in any variable. You can only store the name and directory of image in a variable and access it through these variable.

Comment: how can i do that

Comment: can u give me ur whatsapp no. i need your help